# Cannot generate Apple Certificate Signing Request

Tags: ios

I have built a Phonegap app and am trying to run it on an IPhone 4. One of the many many things required by Apple is a Certificate Signing Request. The instructions for doing so on their website are as follows:

"In the Applications folder on your Mac, open the Utilities folder and launch Keychain Access.
Within the Keychain Access drop down menu, select Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority."

I am completely new to Mac's and am working off a friends computer. Its running OSX 10.8.3. When I launch Keychain Access, there is no Keychain Access drop down with Certificate Assistant. This is what I see: [image]

Where do I find Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access.

Open it and in the "KeyChain Access" menu you'll find "Certificate Assistant."

[image]

Comment: cant believe i missed that, thank u. will accept when it allows me

Comment: Every mac app has a menu under it's own name. Most of the time this is where you will find the application preferences, about, etc. All the top level info.